# Network interface down after every reboot

Tags: networking, server

I have installed Ubuntu server 22.04 for the first time and am still pretty new to linux. Every time I reboot the server I will have to run the command `sudo ifconfig enp6s0f1 up`to get that interface up and running. (I have learned after reading through forums that I should start using ip commands) I have edited my netplan .yaml file and will include it. I have my main interface which doesn't have this issue and a phone tethered to the server that I also do not have this issue with. I've read around and still can't seem to find the solution to my problem. Any advice is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

```
 network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s25:
         dhcp4: true
        enp6s0fl:
         dhcp4: false
        usb0:
         dhcp4: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `.yaml` file has some errors.

First, if you expect your interface to get an IP-address, `dhcp4` should be set to true.

Also, you have the wrong name for your interface - you have written `enp6s0fl`, where it should be `enp6s0f1`. (Maybe you should try another font, so you can clearly distinguish `l` from `1`)

Try this fixed `.yaml` file:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s25:
          dhcp4: true
        enp6s0f1:
          dhcp4: true
        usb0:
          dhcp4: false
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, I think the ip value changes every time you boot. This problem occurs when setting the BOOTPROTO option to dhcp when using redhat.

The way I recommend is to set up a static IP and use it.

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s25:
          dhcp4: true
        enp6s0f1:
          dhcp4: false
          addresses: [x.x.x.x/24]  # Insert IP address of machine
          routes:
            - to: default
              via: y.y.y.y         # Insert IP address of gateway
          nameservers:
            addresses: [z.z.z.z]   # Insert IP address of DNS server
        usb0:
          dhcp4: false
```

Comment: The question was about the interface `enp6s0f1`, not `enp0s25`.

Comment: I made a mistake by confusing the two. Entering the information I entered into enp6s0fl seems to solve the problem.

Comment: To not add further confusions, could you please specify the correct name - `enp6s0f1` as I also state in my post.

Comment: The post has been modified, and addresses and gateway4 can be entered according to the IP address.

Comment: The `gateway4` property is deprecated. It should be replaced with `routes:`. Also, your indentation was not properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Create systemd unit file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/manual-iface.service
   ```

Then add following lines in the file and save it using Ctrl+o and exit using  Ctrl+x:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to bring up/down unconfigured nic enp6s0f1
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/ip link set enp6s0f1 up
ExecStop=/sbin/ip link set enp6s0f1 down

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Then enable the service at boot:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable manual-iface.service
   ```

Comment: Don't you think fixing the `.yaml` file would be a better solution?